# Error when building on new Android Studio 3.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, data-binding, kotlin

I updated Android Studio to 3.1 stable version and get this error, when try to build project. At first there were problems with `DataBinding`, I fixed them, then I found this issue.

```
org.gradle.api.GradleException: Compilation error. See log for more details
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.TasksUtilsKt.throwGradleExceptionIfError(tasksUtils.kt:8)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.processCompilerExitCode(Tasks.kt:415)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:389)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler$kotlin_gradle_plugin(Tasks.kt:251)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:215)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
```

[this is not full version of error logs]

Does anybody find solution?

Comment: post all of your gradle files !!

Comment: yes i also got this error first time after updating android studio. I Just rebuild my project and error gone away.

Comment: Update your project build gradle version and check.

Comment: I updated at first run, it didn't help

Comment: did you solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, I answered below

Comment: @Karamba how did you fix the problems with DataBinding?

Comment: @marioromanolopez yes, look below

Answer (score 2):

This recommendations depends, how much complicated your project(these recommendations can be not usefull):

- Update `Kotlin plugin` to last version
- Remove

  `kapt {
  generateStubs = true
  }`
- If you use databinding, add to `gradle.properties` this line `android.databinding.enableV2=true`
- update gradle
- update build tools

Thanks for my coworkers to find these facts

Comment: You need all this.

Answer (score 0):

Update your kotlin version "1.2.31"
add following dependencies in app level gradle file

> **compile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"**
>
> ```
> android {
>   ...
>
>   sourceSets {
>     main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
>   }
> }
> ```

It may help to you :)

Answer (score 0):

Just checkout this project and see build.gradle files.
I just updated this project for Android Studio 3.1 and met the same error as yours, but everything works well now after some changes in build.gradle.

https://github.com/thierryxing/Douban

The main updates:

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

dependencies {
    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:$gradle_version"
}
```