# Error building project with Android Studio 3.1 and build:gradle 3.1.0

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an issue with new project, I'm trying to build it after updating Android Studio to the 3.1 version, also I have updated gradle to the version 3.1.0, My one project work fine but other project with same setting and with same dependencies when i try to run project shows me error.

There is another question with a similar situation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49509031/error-when-building-on-new-android-studio-3-1) but it is done using kotlin so there should be some differences. And [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49544978/error-building-project-with-android-studio-3-1-and-gradle-3-1-0) also this post **not get answer yet** also.

This is error i got, **but not full** of error log, because it is huge

```
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CompilationFailedException: Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:50)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.JdkJavaCompiler.execute(JdkJavaCompiler.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.delegateAndHandleErrors(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:98)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:51)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.NormalizingJavaCompiler.execute(NormalizingJavaCompiler.java:37)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.execute(CleaningJavaCompilerSupport.java:25)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.compile.incremental.IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.execute(IncrementalCompilationFinalizer.java:24)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.performCompilation(JavaCompile.java:207)
    at org.gradle.api.tasks.compile.JavaCompile.compile(JavaCompile.java:133)
    at com.android.build.gradle.tasks.factory.AndroidJavaCompile.compile(AndroidJavaCompile.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(IncrementalTaskAction.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
    ... 32 more
```

This is my app level gradle file

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chatapp.anu.chatapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:0.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

And this is project level gradle file

```
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You have some syntax error in your Java. The error message gives you a tip: "Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details."

Comment: if i have syntax error it might show in my coding section, but not showing something like that

Comment: some people use down vote but never talking about what wrong with the post. don't put anything unless you cannot say anything about the post. people never figure out the wrong what they did.!

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal Which Android Plugin version are you using?

Comment: @BrijeshShah what you mean by Android Plugin version sir?

Comment: You can check it in the `File > Project Structure > Project` menu in Android Studio. Please let me know which versions you are using.

Comment: 3.1.0 version sir

Comment: and Gradle Version?

Comment: 4.4 version sir

Comment: @SahanPasinduNirmal Can you try to change it `4.6` and let me know if that resolves the issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168481/discussion-between-sahan-pasindu-nirmal-and-brijesh-shah).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution finally. 
I used  **`findViewbByiId`** for each view defined in the layout file to get reference from the XML. 
But in **Android Studio 3.1** **no need use this anymore**.
I simply **remove all `findViewbByiId`** code where i place to get reference from XML widgets, now error has gone.!

Comment: please can you show your java code.  
how to remove **`findViewById`** and add **widgets**

Comment: Ex: private TextView profile_user_name; i can initialize it like this profile_user_name = findViewById(R.id.profile_user_name); this is works in new android studio 3.1 version without adding extra code to data binding.!

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else searching for a solution to this type of build error, I found that down-grading Gradle from 3.1.1 to 3.0.1 would allow it to build.  No other combination of targetSdkVersion, compileSdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, sourceCompatibility, targetCompatibility, or support library versions would work for me.

```
// Example
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1' 
}
```

Comment: Instead of downgrading the plugin, you can add `android.enableD8=false` to `gradle.properties` to force the use of the older pre-3.1.0 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Add buildToolsVersion '27.0.2' in your app level gradle.like this

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.2'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.chatapp.anu.lablayoutwithfragments"
        .....}
```

Comment: If this doesn't work, change your project gradles class path to   
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0-alpha06'

Comment: thank you for the answer, i try both option, it is not worked for me sir

Answer (score 0):

Change all these lines in app individual gradle file to have 27 versions:

```
....
    compileSdkVersion 27
....
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
....
    targetSdkVersion 27
.... 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
....
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
....
```

and make sure you have google() in the top-level build gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: Error still same as previous no change.

Answer (score 0):

I got same problem, everything was fine from my end.
I removed a dependency but its import in the java file was not removed and studio was not showing me any red line error about this. clean and Rebuild project also didnt show the error. Fortunately i opened all my java files and it was found in one of my activities

removing this line and rebuild made my day

[image]

Comment: May be that is the case in your side, but my problem is not like that. I have not use that for my project.

Comment: Any other dependency you may be using, this is the bug from studio end.

Comment: implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:12.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1'

Comment: those are very simple and regular dependencies which all are using.

Comment: It again happened to me today. i changed the edittext (email) id in layout file but forgot to change it in java file, it didnt show any red line error but showed compilation error in build tab. when i visited to java file then it showed red line error at (R.id.email_field). Can i share screenshots in another answer?

Comment: I found the solution finally. 
I used  findViewbByiId for each view defined in the layout file to get reference from the XML. 
But in Android Studio 3.1 no need use this anymore.
I simply remove all findViewbByiId code where i place to get reference from XML widgets, now error has gone.!

Comment: By the way android studio has lunch a new version, that is 3.1.1 did you updated that too?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend updating the gradle plugin to version 3.1.1:

```
   classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.1'
```